# Sitecore experience editor throws error when saving datasource number field

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor

I've created a config item with a number field (without validation rules), I've added a rendering to my page with this config as datasource. When I edit the item in the Content Editor, everything is fine and the number 50.55962 is valid. However, when editing the field in the Experience Editor, Sitecore throws the error below. It is possible to save 50 but not 50.55962 (Which is a valid number), in the Content Editor this gives no problems.

[image]

Any idea what could be the reason for this?
I'm running Sitecore version 8.2 (rev. 170407)

Comment: If you try and save 50,9952 (using a comma), does that work. Wondering if Sitecore has to locale wrong on your site. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/when-to-use-number-vs-integer-field-type

Comment: Hey Chris, I tried it but as I save the datasource, he automatically changes it to a point (50,9952 -> 50.9952). I can't even save the page to see if that works.

Comment: Anything in the logs as this errors?

Comment: No errors whatsoever.

Comment: How are you rendering the number?

Comment: I do get an invalid if I use the comma and it doesn't auto-change it for me to a period.  So, if yours auto-changes, then maybe your locale is incorrect and the "auto-change" is making it incorrect.

Comment: @Marco My locale isn't English but French (Belgium), so I've checked validation on the fields and there is none. It seems like this is default behavior. We've fixed the problem by using single-line text with number validation for now.

Comment: So your decimal separator should be a comma which is why that's invalid.  Now, why is the number you put in with a comma getting updated to a period?  Anyway, you did say you have a workaround but if you want to explore this further, just reply.